# Angular `ng-content` is not working as expected with primeNg tables

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I want to create a reusable table component which uses primeNg to render ui. I created a `table.component.html` and `.ts` for that. Now i want to render content for the table which will be table headers (`th`) and table body (`body`).

To do that, i am writing `th` and `tbody` implementation as a content of table and trying to render it in `table.component.html` using `<ng-content></ng-content>`. But the table is not displaying.

I tried adding the `th` and `tbody` directly in `table.component.html` and it displays the table. shouldn't `ng-content` do the same thing because the content has the same html?

Here is the link to snippet with example. Check `table.component.html` under shared dir. And `app.component.html` for initial start. comment the `ng-content` line and uncomment remaining lines in `table.component.html` and you should see the table.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-kwudxn?file=app%2Fshared%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.html

Comment: Hi - You source doesn't seems to be the working version - check you please check  it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem with your application is that `ng-template` doesn't render anything so `ng-content` doesn't render anything either. I don't see currently any added value in your `TableComponent` as it currently only resends the templates, but that's maybe because it is just a demo and it will have some added value in your case.

You need to change your `TableComponent` to pick up the `PrimeTemplate`s from the content and resend them to `p-table`:

```
export class TableComponent implements AfterContentInit {

    @Input()
    public data: any[];
    @ContentChildren(PrimeTemplate)
    templates: QueryList<any>;
    headerTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
    bodyTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

    constructor() { }

    gePrimeTemplateByType(type: string): PrimeTemplate {
        return this.templates.find(template => {
            return template.getType() === type;
        });
    }

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        this.headerTemplate = this.gePrimeTemplateByType('header').template;
        this.bodyTemplate = this.gePrimeTemplateByType('body').template;
    }
}
```

And in your template:

```
<p-table [value]="data">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="headerTemplate">
        </ng-container>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-data>
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="bodyTemplate; context:{$implicit: data}">
        </ng-container>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Here is complete [forked stackblitz demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-ecyada)

Of course there are other ways to implement this, e.g. your `TableComponent` could have just 2 `@Input`s and just resend them to `p-table` instead of using `PrimeTemplate`s.

Comment: This is was exactly I was trying aside before posting an answer, nice way :) +1

Comment: But I have to admit that, I was trying to load template first and then lazily going to instantiate `p-table` imperatively from Component.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-content` is basically used for `content projection.`  Try using `<ng-template>`  instead of `<ng-content>`

Link:- https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/components/projection.html

### app/child/child.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
    <div style="border: 1px solid blue; padding: 1rem;">
      <h4>Child Component</h4>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `
})
export class ChildComponent {
}
```

### app/app.component.html

```
 <child>
    <p>My <i>projected</i> content.</p>
  </child>
```